# Legion Warrior Artifact Question

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Why is the sword made of dragon scale for warriors artifact in Legions expansion? Who owned it, and why are they so important?

Is it some sort of legendary kings shield with some sort of background to it?

Comment: The developer intent side of this is going to be difficult for us to answer. However, the lore aspect of this question is in fact answerable.

Comment: @twobugs then from a lore side could you give me an answer? Is it some sort of legendary kings shield with some sort of background to it/.

Comment: Answering this from the developer intent side is actually off-topic.  So I'd recommend removing that part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sword and shield in question is the Protection Warrior artifact in World of Warcraft: Legion. The artifact is the sword and shield of an ancient Vrykul (a race of giant humanoids native to Northrend, and likely the progenitors of Humans) king, and they were forged from the scales of Neltharion (AKA Deathwing). Not much else is known at this time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would the downvoter explain why? This is the currently announced lore.

Comment: Previous meta detailed not answering(or pushing) questions that were deliberetly off topic. At the time, OP was deliberetly asking for why the developers put it in. Asking what the artifacts are, this is a good answer. But for asking why blizzard put it in, this is not. Make an edit, tag me in a comment. Cant remove the downvote without it

Comment: @Timelord64 I added some additional information, but this question in it's initial state was asking about the **lore** reason behind this as well. That part was answerable, and it's what I addressed. I'll be more careful about what I answer in the future.